# Converting datatype of a .png image and exporting it as float image

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, geemap

I am trying to convert my uint8 png image to float datatype. First of all, I have tried many libraries that could transform datatypes but I just could not export it as the last datatype I converted for some reason. How can I keep the last datatype while exporting the image to my PC?

In Google Earth Engine, there is this function of image.float(). I could convert my image to float with that function however, when I check the image in QGIS, it is still uint8. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no problem if you convert the image into some format that supports float datatype. TIFF is such a format while png is not. As a proof of concept how it goes with gdal_translate.

Source image is of type "Byte", so Uint8:

```
Band 1 Block=4592x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=4592x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=4592x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Convert into Float32 tiff

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Float32 input.png output.tif
```

Check the result with gdalinfo

```
gdalinfo output.tif
...
Band 1 Block=4592x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=4592x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=4592x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I appreciate that.